# Making Priority Queue of Objects

Tags: c++

I have error in line 7 that missing ; before * I want to make Priority Queue of Objects which gets priority by Student ID and also it is not necessary to have object pointer it can be object itself

```
#include<iostream>   
#include<string>   
using namespace std;   
struct node        
{
    int priority;
    Student * S;
    node * next;
};
class Student
{
    int ID;
    string name;
public:
    Student()
    {
        cin>>ID;
        cin>>name;
    }    
    void out()
    {
        cout<<"ID is : "<<ID<<" "<<"Name is : "<<name<<endl;
    }

};
    class Priority_Queue
{
    node * head;
    //node * back;
public:
    Priority_Queue()
    {
        head=NULL;
        //back=NULL;
    }
    void push(Student * Q, int a)
    {
        node * p=new node;
        p->next=NULL;
        p->priority=a;
        p->S=Q;
        if(head==NULL)
            head=p;
        else
            {
                node * q=head;
                node * r=NULL;
                while(a<=q->priority)
                {
                    r=q;
                    q=q->next;
                }
                r->next=p;
                p->next=q;
            }
    }
    Student * pop()
    {
        if(isempty())
        {
            cout<<"Empty"<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            return head->S;
            head =head->next;
        }
    }
    bool isempty()
    {
        if(head==NULL)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Student S1,S2,S3,S4;
    return 0;
}
```

**Errors in my Code**

```
1>d:\codes\priority queue\priority queue\1.cpp(7): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\codes\priority queue\priority queue\1.cpp(7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\codes\priority queue\priority queue\1.cpp(7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\codes\priority queue\priority queue\1.cpp(41): error C2039: 'S' : is not a member of 'node'
1>          d:\codes\priority queue\priority queue\1.cpp(5) : see declaration of 'node'
1>d:\codes\priority queue\priority queue\1.cpp(66): error C2039: 'S' : is not a member of 'node'
1>          d:\codes\priority queue\priority queue\1.cpp(5) : see declaration of 'node'
```

Comment: For reference: C++ already has a [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).  If you're doing this to learn, though, keep at it.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is, that the `struct node` does not know about the class student, as it is defined after. A workaround is to declare Student before node, but you could aswell put Student in an extra header and include that header in the node header (personally I'd prefer that way.).

```
class Student;
struct node        
{
    int priority;
    Student * S;
    node * next;
};
```

Comment: Oh I cut pasted node after Student it worked I m so mad at myself I wasted about 30 min on it :/

Comment: @user3125340 don't be mad, those are things that happen ;) but I'd recommend you to organize your code by having one header file per class at least, that would prevent most errors like that one...

Answer (score 0):

You should use forward declaration:

```
struct node;
class Student;

struct node
{
    int priority;
    Student * S;
    node * next;
};

// . . .
```